# Windows Worker Service Folder Permissions (C#)

Tags: c#, windows, service, permissions

Quick question if anyone happens to know. I'm working on a Worker app in dotnet6 that is intended to be made into a service and I need to store a json file somewhere. Doing some research it seems like CommonApplicationData(ex: "C:/ProgramData") is the place to go. My question is, I can't seem to write a file to that folder. I am able to create a directory just fine. But my access is denied to creating an actual file.

This service will be used on servers in the field right now and cannot answer UAC prompts. I'm unsure what else to do. I can have the file created manually and access, edit it. That seems to work fine. But I'd like to have a logs files dynamically created and more.

Heres the code("its pretty basic")

```
    var dirPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "MyServerService");
    var path = dirPath + "\\service.json";

    var doesDirExist = Directory.Exists(dirPath);
    var doesFileExist = File.Exists(path);
    if (!doesDirExist || !doesFileExist)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath); //<- directory is created just fine
        using var file = File.Create(dirPath); // <- fails here (access is denied)
        //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: I don't have an installer atm It does seem to only be isolated to create. I can edit the file just fine.

Comment: And no user account. If I understand correctly, you would have to login for services tied to user accounts to work. Most of our servers will sit headless at login screens so that's a no go. It has to be tied to the global local users

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code worked for me. It was indeed a permission issue with the directory being created.

```
  public static bool CreateDirWithAccess(string fullPath, bool readOnly)
{
    var dInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
    DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
    dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), readOnly ? FileSystemRights.Read : FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
    return true;
}
```